# Count distinct unique ID based on multiple row condition and column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How to create measure to count DISTINCT IDs from multiple criteria from specific column?
Below are sample dataset and the condition to create measures.

Criteria: How many unique ID that flows to the prevstepid and stepid using the below condition.

```
CountID Measure 1 = 
Distinctcount ID if prevstepid = "Proc1" and stepid="Verify" and 
prevstepid="Verify" and stepid="Fail" 

CountID Measure 2 = Distinctcount ID  if prevstepid = "Proc1" and 
stepid="Verify" and 
prevstepid="Verify" and stepid="Reg2" and prevstepid="Reg2" and 
stepid="Test2" 

CountID Measure 3 = Distinctcount ID  if prevstepid = "Proc1" and 
stepid="Verify" and 
prevstepid="Verify" and stepid="Proc3" and prevstep="Proc3" and 
stepid="Pass"
```

I tried this code and its not working.

```
Measure 1 = 
 CALCULATE (
 DISTINCTCOUNT ( table[id] ), 
 FILTER (table, table[prevstepid] = "proc1" && table[stepid]="Verify" 
 && table[prevstepid]= "Verify" && table[stepid]="Fail"))
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to double-check whether your Boolean operation is really what you want, e.g. do you really mean AND, or does it makes more sense to use OR? Like condition 1 OR condition 2 is fulfilled, where each condition could be composed of multiple columns’ conditions.

Comment: The flow should always be that way using using the AND condition, it will start with the Proc1 and evaluate if the next step is Verify then check again on the prevstepid if Verify then check again on the next step if fail

Comment: I understand your meaning. But it does not work like this in the measure. The filter expression can never be fulfilled by one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this makes more sense:

```
Measure 1 = 
 CALCULATE (
 DISTINCTCOUNT ( table[id] ), 
 FILTER ( table, ( table[prevstepid] = "proc1" && table[stepid]="Verify" )
 || ( table[prevstepid]= "Verify" && table[stepid]="Fail") ) )
```

I hope you get the idea. Your current Measure 1 is always filtered out, because e.g. you ask for both states at the same time: e.g. “proc1” and “verify”, which none of the rows can fulfill.

In case you want to check both cases are fulfilled, you may want to define e.g. a calculated column to check these 2 conditions and check this helper columns result.

Edit:

For the helper column1:

```
helperColumn1 = 
 CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( table ), 
    ALLEXCEPT ( table, table[id] ),
    ( table[prevstepid] = "proc1" && table[stepid]="Verify" )
    || ( table[prevstepid]= "Verify" && table[stepid]="Fail") 
  )
```

and for measure1:

```
measure1 = 
CALCULATE (
   DISTINCTCOUNT ( table[id] ),
   table[helperColumn1] = 2
)
```

You can do the same way for the measure2 and measure3.

Comment: This will not get the exact result  if I will use the OR. The problem with my dataset the records was display vertically, if I will transpose the structure or design with my dataset to horizontal I think i will get this condition. The issue if I the data will transpose to horizonal i have a lot of different type of prevstepid that will be need to transpose I think 40 different type.

Comment: Yes, you need e.g. a helper calculated column.

Comment: Could ypu please give me an idea for calculated column to check the these 2 condition are fulfill. thanks.

Comment: Another way is to filter the table against the first AND condition and to get the IDs that fulfills. Use this VALUES to filter the table a second time and with the second AND condition.

Comment: I am not with my PC, cannot test. It should work like this: calculated column = count (not distinct) if condition 1 OR condition 2 is fulfilled for each ID row. Measure = distinctcount ID if calculated column = 2 (assuming no duplicates in the data)

Comment: could not figure out this calculated column as helper? may i know if i will be using the switch function or count?

Comment: The idea is to count for each ID how often/how many rows fulfill either of the conditions while not considering any other filters on the other columns. So, using CALCULATE with ALLEXCEPT() should do the trick (instead of IF)

Answer (score 0):

If my data are horizontally distributed , this condition is easy to do but my data are vertically distributed.
the problem with Horizontal i need to manually create column every prevstepid and corresponding stepid and diagnosis column(sample below) with 30 diff. kind of prevstepid. Is there any idea if I can do this dynamically like the below screenshot. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can check for pivot table with PowerQuery to do this. BTW, I added the code for the helper column. Cheers!